# Can we display HTML tables on UILabel (Attributed text)

Tags: ios, objective-c

Up to now i can show some HTML tags like "p", "li" on `UILabel`, but I want to display "td", "tr" tags also. Is it possible? I know we can display in `WKWebView` but for dynamic size in table view i want to put a label kind of UI, is there any third party for it please let me know.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Why not put the `WKWebView` inside your cell? It certainly has been done before, see eg here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48463531

Comment: @saikumar, please check the answer as below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75004837/5581345

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString * htmlString = @"<html><body> Some html string </body></html>";
NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

UILabel * myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
myLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
```

Comment: Code only answers are OK, but adding an explanation is better

Comment: Now i have given more explanation, can you please look in to it

Comment: If you need HTML to show in a View somehwere then UIWebView is the right way to go, you cant upload image so we see whats your real problem can you ?

Comment: @saikumarLakshmiPallagani I don't see any explanation

Answer (score 0):

**UILabel is not suitable to display Table or Image**

We can use TextView or Webview.

> If you want to get height in tableViewCell, you can use textView.

To get attributed String from Html, code as below:

```
extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    var htmlToString: String {
            return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
        }
}
```

display html string in textview as below:

```
cell.txtViewHTML.attributedText = htmlString.htmlToAttributedString
```

To get height of String, code as below:

```
extension String {
    func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [.font : font], context: nil)
        return ceil(boundingBox.height)
    }
    
    func width(withConstrainedHeight height: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [.font : font], context: nil)
        return ceil(boundingBox.width)
    }
}
```

To get height of AttributedString, code as below:

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
        return ceil(boundingBox.height)
    }
    
    func width(withConstrainedHeight height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
        let boundingBox = boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
        return ceil(boundingBox.width)
    }
}
```

Get the height of html string as below:

```
let htmlStringHeight = htmlString.htmlToAttributedString!.height(withConstrainedWidth: screenWidth - 50) + CGFloat(tblViewDefaultHeight)
```

let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds

let screenWidth = screenSize.width

-50, is textview leading and trailing distance in the cell

tblViewDefaultHeight ie., if you want to add some extra spacing

Answer (score -1):

In general, you need an HTML parser to parse the HTML. `UILabel` does not provide this functionality